# Add an If/Else condition at end of my Refresh Data Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which is generated from a button on sheet 1 of my workbook.    When the macro is run it removes password protection from my workbook, refreshes data link with another workbook (the macro takes the user to the directory path but the user has to highlight the workbook and then select OK), the macro then completes by placing password protection back on my workbook.

This works well as long as the user highlights the workbook and selects OK.  If the user should decide to select Cancel the macro will not complete.

Is there an If/Else condition that I could write into the macro to avoid the debug window if the user selects <kbd>Cancel</kbd> instead of highlight the workbook and selecting <kbd>OK</kbd>.  The macro works well without the If/Else element.

```
Sub RefreshData()
'
'RefreshData Macro
'Unprotect, Refresh Data, Protect
'
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With Sheet4
  .Protect Password:="password", UserInterfaceOnly: = True

  ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ThisWorkbook.LinkSources

  If ......... = False Then
  ' Cancel was selected and Data Not Refreshed
  Else
  ' OK was selected and Data Refreshed
  End If

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This would be easier to answer with more information about where "the macro takes the user to the directory path but the user has to highlight the workbook and then select OK".  Is ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink opening a dialog box or is there code that isn't posted above?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GetOpenFilename` to locate the path and file. If the dialog is cancelled, the string which would normally contain the full path and filename becomes a string that states *"False"*.

```
Dim fn As String
fn = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", _
  Title:="Select a workbook to update from")
If fn = "False" Then
    MsgBox "Stopping because you did not select a file"
Else
    ' fn contains the full path and filename. e.g. c:\temp\MyWorkBook.xlsx
    ' wait until you get here before you unprotect the workbook
    Debug.Print CStr(fn)
    ' do the update
    ' reprotect the workbook
End If
```

That is not the same as the boolean value *False*. It's a little out of the ordinary, but the above is the best way I've found to deal with it.

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong here.   The macro runs but I am having to select the full path myself.  If I cancel the MsgBox works and very happy with the element.   However, not sure why I am having to input the full directory path myself.

Comment: The full path is within `fn`. This can be demonstrated by looking at the VBE's Immediate window (Ctrl+G within the VBE) where it is printed out to.

Comment: I am in early stages of learning VB codes.  I am in VBE and selected Ctrl+G which opens the Immediate window but there is nothing in that window.

Comment: If you run the code I supplied and select a file, the full path and filename is stored in `fn`. My code outputs that to the immediate window for checking. You can use it to open the workbook and process the update.